# How do I check to see if the currently logged-in user is in a specific group?

Tags: batch-file, active-directory

I am attempting to create a batch script that changes whether or not a user is in a specific group on Active Directory. I know how to get a list of groups the user is in with this line:

```
whoami \groups
```

What I don't know is how to query that list and run a command based on whether or not a certain group is in that list. I'm looking for something along the lines of:

```
set %groups% whoami \groups
if foo in %groups% echo run
```

This doesn't run (obviously), but I expect the output to be "run" if a group named foo is in the list of groups obtained by `whoami \groups`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try like this:

```
@echo off
set "groupToCheck=BUILTIN\Administrators"

whoami /groups | findstr /B "%groupToCheck:\=\\%\>" >nul 2>&1 && (
  echo I'm in %groupToCheck%
) || (
  echo I'm NOT in %groupToCheck%
)
```

Comment: I ran some more tests on this code. When I set it to a group I am not a part of, it fails to respond with "I'm NOT in notGroup". Instead it responds with "I'm in notGroup".

Comment: I manually confirmed that I was not in the group through Active Directory and whoami \groups.

Comment: I edited this answer to include `\>` at the end to mark the end of the word (which also required escaping any backslashes in `groupToCheck`). Otherwise, this would be matching to substrings of groups. For example, if `groupToCheck` is `BUILTIN\Admin`, it would match to `BUILTIN\Administrators` and would report that you're in `BUILTIN\Admin` even though you aren't.

Comment: After more experimenting of my own, I found that it is possible to hard-code the name of the group to check in place of the variable and it works just fine. Would this run into the same problems that you pointed out with Admin vs. Administrators?

Comment: It depends how you do it. If you hard-code the group name, then make sure to escape any slashes (just put double slash), and use `\>` at the end, like this: `findstr /B "BUILTIN\\Administrators\>"`